# Stored procedure giving me error

Tags: sql-server

I have a stored procedure to change the caption of images at a time..my sp as follows:

```
ALTER Proc [dbo].[sp_RenameAll] @Id nvarchar(MAx), @Captionn nvarchar(20) 

as
begin

DECLARE @List VARCHAR(MAX)

SELECT @List = @Id

EXEC(
'update
 tbl_Images set Caption='+@Captionn+'
WHERE Serial  IN (' + @List + ')'
)
end
```

But when i execute this stored procedure with values

```
  EXEC  @return_value = [dbo].[sp_RenameAll]
    @Id = N'1,2,3',
    @Captionn = N'Newcaption'
```

It is giving me rror as  Invalid column 'Newcaption',
If i change the input values as

```
 EXEC   @return_value = [dbo].[sp_RenameAll]
        @Id = N'1,2,3',
        @Captionn = N'''xxxx'''
```

It is working fine... what is wrong with my Stored procedure????

Comment: That looks like SQL Server, so I have replaced your MySQL tag with SQL Server. Let me know if that's not the case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to change

```
EXEC(
'update
 tbl_Images set Caption='+@Captionn+'
WHERE Serial  IN (' + @List + ')'
)
```

to

```
EXEC(
'update
 tbl_Images set Caption='''+@Captionn+'''
WHERE Serial  IN (' + @List + ')'
)
```

to include quotes around your string value in the dynamic SQL.

Your current stored proc produced this dynamic query:

```
update
tbl_Images set Caption=Newcaption
WHERE Serial  IN (1,2,3)
```

and hence SQL Server thinks `Newcaption` is a column name. But you need

```
update
tbl_Images set Caption='Newcaption'
WHERE Serial  IN (1,2,3)
```

Comment: What do you mean by "more quotes", can you explain a bit more?

Comment: the quotes u hv added in caption...why my sp not working with single quotes '+@Caption+'

Comment: I explained it in the second part of my answer - you need double quote to produce a single quote in the output. Try to see yourself and print the dynamic query you're producing (replace `EXEC` with `PRINT` removing parentheses).